# onListviewclick is not working

Tags: java, android

Hi I made a list menu for my android app and I made the other activities that the menu is link to but when I run it and click on the list item it won't link me to the other activity

codes is here

menu.java (updated)

```
                            package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"Tool","Techniques"} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourclass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Tools.java

```
                 package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

                import android.app.ListActivity;
                import android.content.Intent;
               import android.os.Bundle;
               import android.view.View;
                import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
           import android.widget.ListView;

     public class Tools extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"Counter","Accelermeter","Timer"} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Tools.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Tools.this, ourclass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

       }
```

Technqiues.java

```
                package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

            import android.app.ListActivity;
            import android.content.Intent;
           import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;

         public class Technqiues extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"Kicks","Sparring",} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Technqiues.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Technqiues.this, ourclass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

    }
```

the manifest

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.taekwondobuddy.util"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.taekwondobuddy.util.Menu"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.taekwondobuddy.util.Tools"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Tools" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.taekwondobuddy.util.Techniques"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Techniques" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Any ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy.util." + cheese);
```

for getting class name with full package name because currently you are missing `.util` and also make sure you have added all Activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`

In classes array `"Tkd Buddy"` is not valid class name so use right naming conventions for classes

Comment: just added it in still same problem

Comment: @user2809321 : you are not registering all  `{"Tool","Techniques","Tkd Buddy"}` activities in AndroidManifast

Comment: @user2809321 make sure that the classes name inside the array should be the same with the Java filenames/classes in the manifest.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I included and rename tkd buddy to tkdbuddy and added it to the manifest but still my onclick still doesn't work, is it okay have tkdbuddy in the manifest even tho i didn't create the tkd buddy class yet?

Comment: @user2809321 : you also need to Create an Activity with tkdbuddy name which you are registering in manifest

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yeah so instead of add I took the tkdbuddy out of the array, reran it and it still won't let me link to another menu

Comment: @user2809321 : please show updated code and manifast to get more help

Comment: @user2809321 : change manifast as http://pastebin.com/25P77cqA and Menu class as http://pastebin.com/qEVtM0Tj

Answer (score 0):

change the
within `intent-filter` tag
`action android:name="android.intent.action.Tools`
/intent-filter
to
`android:name="com.example.taekwondobuddy.util.Tools";`

Comment: do I leave in the word action ?